# Why am I getting 404 page not found errors in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

On updating a person's details or a piece of content, like a blog entry, sometimes, although seemingly not all the time, my Drupal 7 website trys to open the following clean urls:

/admin/people
or
/admin/content

rather than

?q=admin/people
or
?q=admin/content

and I get a 404 page not found error.

I have the standard unchanged .htaccess file that comes out of the box.

I have not tried to enable clean urls.

I have added some very standard modules: Insert, Computed Field and CKEditor. That's all.

If it matters, my hosting service is 1&1.

Why am I getting theses 404s? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to actually **enable** clean urls. Perhaps a developer has coded a clean url into the source code by mistake, which is a problem if you do not have clean urls enabled. I think they are enabled by default, but mine were not because, I think, I have my drupal site in a sub-directory. To sort this problem I unremarked RewriteBase in the .htaccess file and added the path of my sub-directory.